# Anyone got struts2-osgi-demo-bundle working?

Tags: struts2, osgi

Here is my code :

https://github.com/hoymkot/struts2-osgi-integration-webapp

I am trying to get struts2-osgi-demo-bundle running with strut2-osgi plugin, but I am getting the following error ...

> Sep 8, 2011 9:32:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   listenerStart SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to
>   listener instance of class
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.listener.StrutsListener Unable to
>   load configuration. - action - bundle://2.0:1/struts.xml:9:64     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:437)    at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.listener.StrutsListener.contextInitialized(StrutsListener.java:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414) Caused
>   by: Unable to load configuration. - action -
>   bundle://2.0:1/struts.xml:9:64    at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:380)
>     at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:424)
>     ... 26 more Caused by: Action class [helloWorldAction] not found -
>   action - bundle://2.0:1/struts.xml:9:64   at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:420)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:365)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:479)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:275)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.osgi.BundlePackageLoader.loadPackages(BundlePackageLoader.java:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.osgi.OsgiConfigurationProvider.loadConfigFromBundle(OsgiConfigurationProvider.java:131)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.osgi.OsgiConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(OsgiConfigurationProvider.java:96)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:215)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
>     ... 28 more Sep 8, 2011 9:32:27 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop SEVERE:
>   Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of
>   class org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.listener.StrutsListener
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.listener.StrutsListener.contextDestroyed(StrutsListener.java:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4245)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4886)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4750)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414) Sep 8,
>   2011 9:32:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO:
>   ContextListener: contextInitialized() Sep 8, 2011 9:32:31 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: SessionListener:
>   contextInitialized()

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The main error is:
Caused by: Action class [helloWorldAction] not found - action - bundle://2.0:1/struts.xml:9:64 at

struts.xml from the demo bundle contains wron definitions for action class:

```
<action name="hello-velocity" class="helloWorldAction">
    <result type="velocity">/content/osgi/hello.vm</result>
</action>
<action name="hello-freemarker" class="helloWorldAction">
    <result type="freemarker">/content/osgi/hello.ftl</result>
</action>
```

Try to change the fragment of struts.xml to

```
<action name="hello-velocity" class="actions.osgi.HelloWorldAction">
    <result type="velocity">/content/osgi/hello.vm</result>
</action>
<action name="hello-freemarker" class="actions.osgi.HelloWorldAction">
    <result type="freemarker">/content/osgi/hello.ftl</result>
</action>
```